# Owl Carousel is set as display none

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I try to use Owl Carousel, but I can't make it work. I tried to use both cdn and from my files. The div is set as display none.Not sure why I am doing wrong. Owl folder is from there website, but I renamed.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/owl/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/owl/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"/>

<body>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme mt-5">
    <div class="item"><h4>1 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12 testing</h4></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/docs/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you check your console? Are there any js error?

Comment: It does work tho https://jsfiddle.net/wksdrxug/

Comment: Ohh, I found the problem, I had the script for Jquery above my script and It didn't know  " $  ". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<body>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme mt-5">
    <div class="item"><h4>1 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12 testing</h4></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the script for jQuery and OwlCarousel is below the script where you're initializing OwlCarousel. 
As a result, OwlCarousel is not being recognized as a global.
The display is, therefore, being set to none, which is the default behavior when OwlCarousel is not initialized for that element.

Try the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/owl/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/owl/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"/>

<body>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme mt-5">
    <div class="item"><h4>1 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11 testing</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12 testing</h4></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/docs/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            margin:10,
            nav:true,
            responsive:{
                0:{
                    items:1
                },
                600:{
                    items:3
                },
                1000:{
                    items:5
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same issue.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/docs/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/owl/dist/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:5
            }
        }
    })
});
```